# Hibernate - map weird multidirectional relationship (without foreign keys)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have three tables set up like so (not my design):

**Tables 'Foo' & 'Bar':**

```
----------   ----------
| FOO_ID |   | BAR_ID |  
----------   ----------  
|      1 |   |      1 |  
|      2 |   |      3 |
----------   ----------
```

**Nothing special here, they are just two tables with ids*

**Table 'Annotation':**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| ANNOTATION_ID | ANNOTATION_TEXT | OTHER_TABLE | OTHER_ID |
------------------------------------------------------------
|             1 |  'annotation a' |       'foo' |        1 |
|             2 |  'annotation b' |       'foo' |        2 |
|             3 |  'annotation c' |       'baz' |        1 |
|             4 |  'annotation d' |       'baz' |        3 |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ok, so this 'annotaion' table is literally referencing the foo and baz tables by name and primary key. There's absolutely no referential integrity here. It's not my design.

Disclaimers aside, in SQL the `join` would be like:

```
select *
from foo
left join annotation
on (other_table = 'foo' and other_id = foo_id)
```

I want to map this relationship using Hibernate with annotations. I'm afraid it's not possible but wanted to ask, you never know. My `Annotation` class would look like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANNOTATION")
public class Annotation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ANNOTATION_ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "ANNOTATION_text")
    private String text;
    @Column(name = "OTHER_TABLE")
    private Integer other_table;
    @Column(name = "OTHER_ID")
    private Integer other_id;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Any ideas how do I set up this one-to-many (one `Foo` to many `Annotations`) mapping in Hibernate?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FOO_ID")
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany
    @Column // how would I configure this?
    private Collection<Annotation> annotations;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Comment: Can you add tables to the schema? Maybe a view or two?

Comment: @BoristheSpider if that's the best solution I'm open to suggestions, cheers.

Comment: I think there's some hibernate wizardry that can be done - maybe one of the gurus will come along and demonstrate. I would suggest using views to split the table into two tables with a more traditional structure; you can also add triggers on insert to set the `OTHER_TABLE` value to the correct one.